# how to create a corner angle over a textbox?

Tags: javascript, html, css, textbox

I want to create a corner at the right top corner of a textbox like in below image.
[image]

how can I do it using css?

I have the following text box on which I have to apply the right corner

```
.up {
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 25px 25px 0 0;
border-color: #489af2 transparent transparent transparent;
position:relative;
}


.textbox{
 width:43px;
 height:23px;
 text-align:right;
 padding-bottom:0px;
 padding-top:4px;
 position:absolute;
}

.up p {

top: -35px;
left: 2px;
position: relative;
z-index:1;
color:#FFF;
font-size:11px;
font-weight:bold;
//transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

<input type="number" class="textbox"/>
<div class="up">
<p>3.9</p>
</div>
```

[JsFiddle for the above code](https://jsfiddle.net/c1c2ai/2shvpek6/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using an `::after` element to avoid additional markup.

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.wrap textarea {
  height: 120px;
}
.wrap::after {
  content: '';
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-top: solid 1px #ff9000;
  border-right: solid 1px #ff9000;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: tried to apply the code for my textbox  but messed up a bit, have updated the question with my custom textbox.

Comment: So you're just trying to get it to be on the right side? What is messed up about it?

Answer (score 1):

Use an absolute element which is positioned in the right top and has a border to right and top.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.wrapper .shape {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  right: -10px;
  top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <div class="shape"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All the answers are good so far but seeing as I was already typing out my version I'll just post it here anyways.

```css
.myText{
 width: 200px;
 position: relative; 
 padding: 5px 10px 0 0;
}
.myText input{
 width: 100%; 
}
.myText:after{
 content: "";
 display: block; 
 width: 15px;
 height: 15px;
 border-top: 1px solid black;
 border-right: 1px solid black;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="myText">
 <input type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.corner{
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  width:20px;
  height:10px;
  margin-left:160px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="corner">
</div>
  <input type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put your textbox inside a container and add 2 pseudo element (`:before` and `:after`).

```
.container {
position: relative;
padding: 5px;
}

.container:before,
.container:after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
background: #000;
}

.container:before {
width: 30px;
height: 1px;
}

.container:after {
width: 1px;
height: 30px;
}
```